# Can I connect wall sconces to an existing switched circuit?

Tags: electrical, lighting

My den has four outlets tied to one wall switch (top receptacle at each outlet). I am looking to install four sconces (two per wall on two walls) and was wondering if I can tie these into the existing switched outlets.

I am sure this CAN be done, but more wondering if it is OK to do. Will this violate code (Minnesota USA). Or should I run new cable and use a new switch?

Comment: Yes it would be possible, but I'm not really sure what your question is - are you looking for a yes/no, or instructions on how you'd accomplish that?

Comment: @Steven I edited my question to better show this, but basically I am looking for a yes\no\Don't even think about that type answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically, yes you can tie into those outlets for power.

Whether or not it is safe (and not against code) to do so would depend on what other loads are already on the circuit (will adding the lights overload the circuit?) and the size of the electrical boxes where the outlets are located (are they large enough to accommodate the wires from another branch?).

You would need to do some load calculations taking into consideration the wire gauge as well as box fill calculations.  This information is available in the NEC - always a handy reference to have available when doing this type of work.

If in doubt, it's always safest to consult a licensed electrician.